# $y=f(x)$ is differentiable, has inverse function $x=g(y)$ and $ x^3 = y^4 +x^2\sin y +1$. Find $f'(1)$ and $g'(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$y=f(x)$ is differentiable, has inverse function $x=g(y)$ and $ x^3 = y^4 +x^2\sin y +1$.

Knowing that $f(1) = 0$ find $f'(1)$ and $g'(0)$.

I know that $g'(0)=\frac{1}{f'(1)}$.

How to make use of the given equation? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Differentiate it and put $x=1,y=0$. You should get $y'=3$, which is the same as $f'(1)=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate both sides in respect of $x$, then
$$
3x^2=4y^3\frac{dy}{dx}+2x\sin y +x^2\cos y \frac{dy}{dx}.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{3x^2 - 2x \sin y}{4y^3+x^2\cos y}
$$
and so
$$
\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=1} =\frac{3 - 0}{0+\cos 0}=3.
$$

Comment: In my country we're not used to Leibniz's notation. In order to differentiate with respect to x, I substituted $y = f(x)$ and got this:

$ 3x^2 = 4f^3(x)f'(x) + 2x\sin (f(x)) + x^2 \cos(f(x))f'(x) $, and plugged $x=1$ to get $f'(1) = 3$. Is that good?

Comment: That is identical to my formula.

Comment: Yes, sorry for asking such a trivial thing but I have seen $\frac{dx}{dy}$ notation very rarely, and treating it as a fraction, or doing any kind of operations with it is very confusing for me. Thanks for claryfying.